# Assign the value of a row to a global Variable

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5, sqlite

Hy all, 
using sqlite3 with tableviews, the fact of passing data from a tableView to a view controller did not actually work.( Tried the prepare of segue and did not work )
So instead i was trying to assign the content of the selected row into a global variable accessed then by the 2nd view controller.
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .h file, i should declare it as extern variable, and in every .m file declare it normally, in that case we will have access to the variable globally.